# Yii CListView select last page, after update

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, comments

i have a problem.
I use ajax comment adding, so i need to update listview. And i need to select last page of the listview after that.

A can select last page on load, using this

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($model->comments);
$pager=$dataProvider->pagination;
$pager->itemCount=$dataProvider->totalItemCount;
if(!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
   $pager->currentPage=$pager->pageCount;
```

I can  manual update clistview

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update("commentsList");
```

But, i cant do this things together :)
I also tried to pass the data array, to the javascript function update.
So, i need to add comment using ajax, then i need to update clistview and select last page. Any ideas, how can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried displaying the comments in reverse order?

Comment: of course :) but i interested in asc odrder, i think it is more handy.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could trigger a `click` event on the "Last page" button of the pager.

```
$('#pagination li.last a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: thank you, i think i'll use it, if there is no more native solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Аfter several attempts, i finally made the desired behavior. It was harder, than i expected, maybe there is more simple way, but i have what i have.

So, i used

```
div.keys
```

That CListView uses to provide url data for update.

Each time when user adds or delete comment, we call update method

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('commentsList');
```

That takes title attr from div.keys.
So i decided to change title attr manually, before calling update method.
I also needed information about total page number, so i add class to my commentsList

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'/comment/_comment',
            'id'=>'commentsList',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                "class"=>$pager->pageCount,
            ),
        ));
```

I wrote function to get all information

```
var getUrlInfo = function() {
    var divKeys = commentsBlock.find('div.keys'),
        keys = divKeys.attr('title'),
        currentPage = "",
        lastPage = parseInt (commentsBlock.find('#commentsList').attr('class')) +1, 
        temp = keys.lastIndexOf("page=") + 5,
        pageNumberIndex = temp;

    while ( !isNaN(parseInt(keys[temp])) ) {
            currentPage +=keys[temp];
            temp++;
    };

    return {'divKeys':divKeys, 'keys':keys, 'currentPage':currentPage,     'lastPage':lastPage, 'pageNumberIndex':pageNumberIndex};
};
```

And after that, i set rules to change the title attr for adding comment
    var urlInfo = getUrlInfo();
    if (urlInfo.currentPage.length) { 
                    urlInfo.divKeys.attr(
                            'title', 
                            urlInfo.keys.slice(0,urlInfo.pageNumberIndex) + urlInfo.lastPage + urlInfo.keys.slice(urlInfo.pageNumberIndex + urlInfo.currentPage.length) 
                        );
                }

```
            else { 
                if (urlInfo.keys.indexOf('ajax')>0) 
                    {
                        urlInfo.divKeys.attr('title', urlInfo.keys + "&page=" + urlInfo.lastPage);
                    }
                else urlInfo.divKeys.attr('title', urlInfo.keys + "?page=" + urlInfo.lastPage);
            }
```

and for deleting comment functions

```
var urlInfo = getUrlInfo();

            if (!urlInfo.currentPage.length) { 
                console.log('da');
                if (urlInfo.keys.indexOf('ajax')>0) 
                    {
                        urlInfo.divKeys.attr('title', urlInfo.keys + "&page=" + urlInfo.lastPage);
                    }
                else urlInfo.divKeys.attr('title', urlInfo.keys + "?page=" + urlInfo.lastPage);
            }
```

I also set this rule for my view.php

```
if(!Yii::app()->request->getQuery('ajax') && !Yii::app()->request->getQuery('page')) {
            $pager->currentPage=$pager->pageCount;
        }
```

Comment: The last PHP part is the interessing one.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works for me with appending a parameter to the $.fn.yiiListView.update function

JS Part:

```
 $.fn.yiiListView.update('switchlist-designer-clistview',{
                  data: $(this).serialize()+"&gotoLastPage=true",
                  complete:function(){
                    //Ajax loading is finished           
                  });
```

PHP Part in your Controller

```
if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam("gotoLastPage")=="true"){
      //Important to unset the gotoLastPage Parameter otherwise the pagination wont work
       unset($_GET["gotoLastPage"]);

      //Get the last page 
      $lastPage = ceil($activeDataProvider->getTotalItemCount()/$activeDataProvider->getPagination()->pageSize);

      //Set the lastpage
      $paginator->currentPage=$lastPage;
      $activeDataProvider->setPagination($paginator);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change url option like this:

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('productslistview', { 
    url: 'http://domain/search/controller?str=test&Controller_page=' + pageNumber + '&ajax=listview'
})
```

And last page you can get on php side from your dataProvider:

```
$dataProvider->getCount()
```